# determining user location with near pinoint accuracy iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, core-location, cllocationmanager

My application is EXTREMELY dependent on user location, so much so that accuracy is very crucial to the use of the app. Speaking with my team we have realized the scenario that if a user is in close proximity to another geofence that we have created, CoreLocation may not recognize the difference. Are there currently any frameworks that work better for CL or LocationManager in iOS. I check the Cocoapods library but they all seem pretty close to one another in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overcome the physical and technological limitations of the GPS system. If you call CLLocationManager's `requestLocation` when the location manager is configured with the highest desired degree of `desiredAccuracy` (namely `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`), the response in `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` is as accurate is you are going to get. Using a "library" is not going to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation and then you will get the best data available. If you are not happy with iOS handling of geofences you could try to implement the geofence thing yourself by just subscribing to the delegate methods.

That way you can also filter CLLocations with a low accuracy and ignore them for example.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there no magic bullet to give you accuracy better than what the GPS is able to provide.

What you can do is

1. Set the desiredAccuracy to the max
2. Check the accuracy value you get back from location updates, and reject readings with a horizontal "accuracy" value that is too large (since the "accuracy" reading is actually a "circle of confusion" or radius in meters where the phone may actually be located.

Note that step 2 may cause it to take a LONG time to get an acceptable location fix, or you may not be able to get an acceptable reading at all. Based on the testing I did several years ago, requiring a horizontal accuracy reading of 16 meters was the best I was able to achieve, and I could only get that signal quality in an open area free of buildings and without a lot of tree cover. (I haven't tried it in an open prairie, however.)